# Magento 1.9 var/session directory not generating any files

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I don't know whats going wrong with my Magento 1.9 setup. From last few days I have seen my /var/session directory remains same with no files generated. It's showing empty content.

My

Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management
Has below data

Cookie Lifetime : 3600

Cookie Path :

Cookie Domain : .domain.com

Use HTTP Only : Yes

Cookie Restriction Mode : No

Please suggest how to resolve this issue or this is not a problem. It's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `local.xml` file in `app/etc/local.xml`.  Under the `<session_save>` node, does it say *files*?  If not, your sessions are probably saved in the storage engine designated in that node.

If it does say *files*, check to ensure your `var/` directory is fully writable (`chmod 777` permissions).  If it isn't, they are probably being saved in you `/tmp/magento` directory in your linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

It is deffinitelly an access rights issue. Make sure to set the /var/session/ folder writable "by others"